# Gram matrix without loops

Tags: r, matrix

I need to find a Gram matrix G from column vectors of matrix H, e.g. H = [h_1, h_2, ..., h_m] and G[i, j] = (h_i , h_j) for each i, j from 1 to m, where ( , ) denotes a dot product. I have written the following code in R:

```
Gram <- function(H)
{
  m <- dim(H)[2]

  G <- matrix(NA, m, m)
  for(i in 1:m)
    for(j in 1:m)
      G[i, j] <- H[, i] %*% H[, j]

  G
}
```

Is there any way to avoid loops?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to type: `G <- matrix(NA, m, m)`

Comment: I also think you missplaced a comma in the dot product `H[,i] %*% H[j,]`.

Comment: Is just `t(H) %*% H` or `crossprod(H)` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Seth no. H is nxm matrix and in your notation vectors H[, i] and H[j, ] have different dimensions as long as n not equal to m.

Comment: @nicola Oh, thanks! How could I miss that?